# Cache inconsistency - Entity not always persisted in cached Collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, ehcache

I'm having an issue where a `Validation` instance is added to a Collection on a `Step` instance.
Declaration is as follows:

Step class:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Step extends AbstractEntity implements ValidatableStep {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "step_id", nullable = false)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Validation> validations = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void addValidation(Validation validation) {
      // do some stuff
      ...
      // add validation instance to collection
      getValidations().add(validation);
    }

}
```

Validation class:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Validation extends AbstractEntity {
  //some properties
}
```

Both classes are `Cacheable` with a `READ_WRITE` strategy applied. The unidirectional Collection of `Validation`s are also cached with same strategy.

One would expect when a read-write transaction that invokes `addValidation(new Validation('userName'));` commits, the new `Validation` would be visible in a subsequent read-only transaction. The weird thing is that sometimes it does work and sometimes it doesn't work...

The first transaction always succeeds; we see the new validation being persisted in database and `Step`'s version property (for optimistic locking puposes) getting incremented. But sometimes, the 2nd read transaction contains a `Step` instance with an empty `Validation` Collection...

Our Hibernate caching config is as follows:

```
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache = true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class = org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path = classpath:ehcache.xml
net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.cache_lock_timeout = 10000
```

Any idea what's causing this weird (and random) behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Hibernate Collection Cache](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-collection-cache-work/) always invalidates existing entries and both the Entity and the Collection caches are sharing the same [AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cache/ehcache/internal/strategy/ReadWriteEhcacheEntityRegionAccessStrategy.html), so a [soft-lock is acquired](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-read_write-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/) when updating data.

Because you are using a unidirectional one-to-many association, you will end up with a `Validation` table and a Step_validation link table too. Whenever you add/remove a Validation you have to hit two tables and that's less efficient.

I suggest you adding the `@ManyToOne` side in the `Validation` entity and turn the `@OneToMany` side into a mapped-by collection:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "step")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
private Set<Validation> validations = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Actually, I don't have a link table. Validation just has a foreign key to Step. So an add/remove should trigger only one table. Anyway, I made my relationship bidirectional and that did the trick! However, I don't understand why 2nd level cache requires a bidirectional relationship? My application is full of one directional ones (because bi is not always meaningful). Does this mean I have to refactor all relationships? I use on all Collections a NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE or READ_WRITE caching strategy...

Comment: The `Step` is the Parent of the association and the `Validation` is the Child. In a Parent-Child relationship, the Parent is the one-to-many side and it's better to be mapped-by as well. Often, you can turn this into a unidirectional association, which requires removing the one-to-many side and leaving only the many-to-one association. A unidirectional one-to-many association is always uses a link table and that's not very practical.